# Master pages in .net

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

i have two root master pages RootMaster1 and RootMaster2 and one child Master page how can a child master page select his parent master page dynamically in c#.

all my website pages inherits from child master page. the main problem is on run time selection

thanks in advance

Comment: do accept answer if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

To access a method in the immediate master page from a content page you need to ensure that in the master page code-behind file you declare public access for the method you want to call. Having done this, you can access a method in a master page from your content page by using the code in Listing 1 and replacing ClassName with the name of your code-behind class, and MasterMethod() with the name of the master page method you will be accessing.

```
ClassName MasterPage = (ClassName)Page.Master;
MasterPage.MasterMethod();
```